# Cohomology of the Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, riemann-sphere

Let us note $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ the Alexandroff compactification of $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. the Riemann Sphere). I can prove that $$H^1(\overline{\mathbb{C}},\Omega_{\overline{\mathbb{C}}}) \simeq \mathbb{C},$$ where $\Omega_\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ is the sheaf of holomorphic one-forms. However, I would like to prove that the integration on $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ : $$\int : H^1(\overline{\mathbb{C}},\Omega_{\overline{\mathbb{C}}}) \to \mathbb{C}$$ is an isomorphism. I tried some Mayer-Vietoris sequences but can't get the conclusion.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit** I think I can prove surjectivity. Consider $\omega_0 = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\frac{dz}{z}.$ Then $\int [\omega_0] = 1$ and hence for all $a \in \mathbb{C}$ $$\int a [\omega_0] =a.$$ The injectivity remains a problem, how can I prove that $\int \omega =0$ implies that $\omega = \partial \omega'$ for a $\omega'$ ?

Comment: It's spelled "prove" (one "o").

Comment: Note: $\omega_{0}$ is a one-form, which you're trying to integrate over a two-dimensional object. Probably you want to invoke the Dolbeault theorem (first cohomology with coefficients in the sheaf of holomorphic one-forms is isomorphic to the $(1, 1)$-Dolbeault cohomology) and construct a smooth, real $(1, 1)$-form integrating to $1$ over the sphere. Then argue that the Dolbeault cohomology is one-dimensional, since the two-dimensional deRham cohomology of the sphere is one-dimensional.

Comment: I should have precised it but indeed I define the integral thanks to Dolbeault theorem. Oh yes, if I understand your argument, surjectivity is enough since we have two $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces with the same dimension ?

Comment: Yes, I corrected the typo, thanks.

Comment: 1. The commonly-used smooth $(1, 1)$-form is the area form of the round sphere of unit area,$$\omega_{0} = \frac{i\, dz\, d\bar{z}}{2\pi(1 + |z|^{2})^{2}}.$$2. Yes, surjectivity is enough if you know $h_{\bar{\partial}}^{1,1} = h_{d}^{2} = 1$.